# calling perl program from tclsh with -open and -close as arguments to it

Tags: perl, tcl

I am new to Perl and Tcl. I am trying to build upon existing Tcl code to make my own script.
The problem is when i try to use and exisiting perl program from my tcl script it gives following error:

```
***invalid command name "*'"
while executing
"*' \
                    -close '*"
invoked from within
"set command "/usr/local/bin/perl /home/bin/perlscript \
                    -var SOURCE=$myings \
                    -var IN_LA..."***
```

My code inside the tcl script looks something like below:

```
set command "/usr/local/bin/perl /home/bin/perlscript \
                             -var SOURCE=$myings \
                             -var IN_LAYMAN=TRUE \
                             -open '[*' \
                             -close '*]' \
                             -open '[*' -close '*]' $mygsp -output run.file"

if {   [ file exists $mygsp ] && [file exists $myings ] } {
    if { [catch { open "|$command" } input] } {
           putmsg "Please check the following errors: $::errorInfo"
          } else {
           putmsg " Either the $mygsp or $myings is missing. Please check before   proceeding forward"
             }
}
```

I suspect the problem to be in the usage of 'open' & 'close' or the '[*' spl charectors. can you help?

Answer (score 2):

All the '[' characters inside the double-quote-delimited string have to be escaped, otherwise TCL tries to execute the commands within [...] block and substitute the result into the string:

```
set command "/usr/local/bin/perl /home/bin/perlscript \
                         -var SOURCE=$myings \
                         -var IN_LAYMAN=TRUE \
                         -open '\[*' \
                         -close '*]' \
                         -open '\[*' -close '*]' $mygsp -output run.file"
```